# Sending data to a MySQL database in a desktop application from a GPRS module

Tags: java, gprs

I want to develop a software which gets data periodically(daily) from a GPRS modem and saving it to a database(MySQL database) which is installed in a PC. I would like to know a method to implement this. My lecturer suggest me to use a cloud database. So first data is send from the GPRS to the Cloud database and then the software which I'm developing get these data from this cloud db and saving it to a local database and then using these data for further use. Is there any other method to do implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend a cloud database. It's not a good pratice have your client application (GPRS module + some microcontroller or microchip) connecting direct to your database (for safety and performance resons). You should use webservice (client / server protocols such as HTTP). A very easy way to do it is use PHP + MySQL, you can find really cheap "webpage" servers for like $5/month and they are ready to go. In your client (GPRS module) you can send somethink like:

```
GET /v1/methodXXX/?data1=dataHere&data2=MoreData HTTP/1.0
Host: yourwebsitedomain.com
```

And in your php v1/methodXXX page:

```
<?php
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;port=xxx;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLEHERE (id, data1, data2) VALUES (NULL, :data1, :data2)");

    $stmt ->bindValue(':data1', $_GET['data1']);
    $stmt ->bindValue(':data2', $_GET['data2']);

    $stmt->execute();

?>
```